# How to create a multiline tripple quote `ast` node string in python?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there a way of creating an `ast` node of a tripple quote multiline python string (like in `docstrings`)? I am creating a python module to use the OpenAI API for auto-generating docstrings with GTP and inserting them directly into the python file. A simplified version of what I have is:

```py
import ast                                                                        

class DocstringWriter(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
        docstring = ast.get_docstring(node)
        new_docstring_node = self.make_docstring_node(docstring)
        if docstring:
            node.body[0] = new_docstring_node
        else:
            node.body.insert(0, new_docstring_node)
        return node

    def make_docstring_node(self, docstring):
        docstring = """New docstring\nwith maybe some new lines"""
        s = ast.Str(docstring)
        return ast.Expr(value=s)
```

For example, this gives:

```py
def esc(s):
    "\n\nesc(s)\n\nReturns a string with all backslashes escaped.\n\nParameters\n----------\ns : str\n    The string to escape.\n\nReturns\n-------\nstr\n    The escaped string.\n\nExamples\n--------\n>>> esc('\\\\')\n'\\\\\\\\'\n\n"
    return s.translate(str.maketrans({'\\': '\\\\'}))
```

When it should return:

```py
def esc(s):
    """
    esc(s)
    
    Returns a string with all backslashes escaped.
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    s : str
        The string to escape.

    Returns
    -------
    str
        The escaped string.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> esc('\\\\')
    '\\\\\\\\'

    """
    return s.translate(str.maketrans({'\\': '\\\\'}))
```

Comment: It works well on my machine (Python 3.10.8, Windows10). How do you use it to insert docstrings?

Comment: The kind of quotes you use isn't reflected in the AST. Single quotes, double quotes, and the triple-quoted variety of each all produce `Constant` nodes. `ast.Str`is deprecated and just returns an instance of `ast.Constant`. The level of control you want requires a *concrete* syntax tree, such as can be produced and manipulated by the 3rd-party module [LibCST](https://pypi.org/project/libcst/).

Comment: (For example, [`libcst.SimpleString`](https://libcst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nodes.html#libcst.SimpleString) objects have a `quotes` property that records the style of quotation marks associated with the string literal.)